# Can't pass the value in php function using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I created the function for my site the users will click the images according to the clicked image I showing the clicked image details so I created the **onclick** function and I passing that image **ID** using the ajax function I passing the image ID in PHP file and get that ID into post method and same time passing that variable into PHP class function. My issue is inside the script ID is coming but php file I can't get that variable I don't understand what is the issue. Please help me to find out this issue.

**This is the clickable image with onclick function**

```
<div class=\"col-md-3\">
       <div class=\"single-new-trend\">
            <a href=\"#\" id='BandChangeImg$BraproId' onclick='ImageChange($BraproId);'>
               <img src=\"$BraProImg\" alt=\"$BraProName\"></a>
       </div>
</div>
```

**This is my ajax script**

```
function ImageChange(x) {
    var BrandName = x;

    alert(BrandName);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'validate/brandImage.php',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {BrandId:BrandName},
        success:function(data){
            //alert(data);
            if($.trim(data))
            {
                alert("Success!");
            }else{
                alert("Failed!")
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Last My PHP file**

```
<?php

include("../db/mySqlDBi.class.php");
$DBConn = new mySqlDB;

$BrandId = $_POST['BrandId'];


include("../classes/personlized.class.php");
$personlized = new personlizedClass;

$result=$personlized->DisplayBrandProductDetails($BrandId);



echo "<script>alert('12334');</script>";

?>
```

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request/response in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: I try nothing is showing

Comment: There is nothing showing in the request?

Comment: Yes, it is empty.

Comment: Where is the `$BraproId` variable coming from? Why are you escaping the double quotes?

Comment: In the first code, I uploaded HTML onclick function

Comment: I'm asking where it comes from in the html. Is `alert(BrandName);` working properly?

Comment: Yes, it's working. First, two alert's are working properly

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? Seems the JS is working but the JQuery isn't.

Comment: No, I didn't get any error in the console

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
dataType: "json",
```

in the `$.ajax` call. jQuery will try to parse the response as JSON, and will get an error if this fails.

The script is sending

```
echo "<script>alert('12334');</script>";
```

That's HTML, not JSON, so the above error happens.

Either change it to `dataType: "html"` or change the PHP to something like

```
echo json_encode("Brand is $BrandId");
```

Comment: I changed to "echo json_encode("Brand is $BrandId");" not success.